# How to re-attach animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I re-attach the following animation?
So that every time the text is been clicked, the animation will be activated?

Currently, if I click the text, for the first time the animation will be activated, but no longer when clicking again.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.shakeit {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }

    20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }

    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }

    40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id='xxx' class="">JavaScript Numbers</h2>
<script>
const x = document.getElementById('xxx');
x.addEventListener('click', () => {
    x.classList.add("shakeit");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onanimationend  event to remove the class again after its finished.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.shakeit {
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }

    20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }

    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }

    40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id='xxx' class="">JavaScript Numbers</h2>
<script>
const x = document.getElementById('xxx');
x.addEventListener('click', () => {
    x.classList.add("shakeit");
});
x.onanimationstart = function(event) {
  console.log("Animation started", event);
}

x.onanimationend = function(event) {
  x.classList.remove("shakeit");
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```